# Return a for loop inside a function

Tags: javascript, function, for-loop, return

i have a function with a for loop inside it, this function should later display the values, something like a Button click handler.
How can i return the values (in this case 10 times) in this for loop instead a console.log(), if i try with return statement, after 1 iteration logically break return the loop.

```
const handleCalculate = () => {
  let price = 6.60;
  let growthRate = 12.35;
  let yearlyGrowth = (growthRate * price) / 100;
  let currentPrice = price + yearlyGrowth;
  // should output 10 times
  for (let i = 0; i <= 10; i++) {
    currentPrice += yearlyGrowth;
    currentPrice = Math.round(currentPrice * 100) / 100;
    // how can i return each values instead of console.log() ?
    console.log(currentPrice);
  }
}
handleCalculate();
```

**EDIT !**
first Thank at all for quick answer!
i modifying my Code and work fine, but i wanna know it is a good practice? Can you improved it?

```
// Calculate growing fish price
const growthCalculator = () => {
  const price = 6.60;
  const growthRate = 12.35;
  const yearlyGrowth = (growthRate * price) / 100;
  const result = [];

  let currentPrice = price + yearlyGrowth;

  // Calculate each growing fish price and round it to 2 decimal
  for (let i = 0; i <= 10; i++) {
    currentPrice += yearlyGrowth;
    currentPrice = Math.round(currentPrice * 100) / 100;

    // push result in new array
    result.push(currentPrice);
  }
  return result;
}
const result = growthCalculator();

//Loop thru result array and display fish price
const handleCalculator = () => {
  let summe = '';
  result.forEach(element => {
    summe += element + "<br>";
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = summe;
  });
}
// display result by button click
document.getElementById("btn").addEventListener('click', handleCalculator);
```

Answer (score 1):

Aggregate your results in an array, and return the array:

```js
const handleCalculate = () => {
  const price = 6.60;
  const growthRate = 12.35;
  const yearlyGrowth = (growthRate * price) / 100;
  const result = [];
  
  let currentPrice = price + yearlyGrowth;
  
  for (let i = 0; i <= 10; i++) {
    currentPrice += yearlyGrowth;
    currentPrice = Math.round(currentPrice * 100) / 100;
    
    result.push(currentPrice);
  }
  
  return result;
}

const result = handleCalculate();

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

One solution would be to create an array inside of `handleCalculate()` that stores the `currentPrice` value of each iteration, and then return that array after the loop has completed:

```js
const handleCalculate = () => {

  /*Declare empty array like this */
  let resultsArray = [];

  let price = 6.6;
  let growthRate = 12.35;
  let yearlyGrowth = (growthRate * price) / 100;
  let currentPrice = price + yearlyGrowth;

  for (let i = 0; i <= 10; i++) {
    currentPrice += yearlyGrowth;
    currentPrice = Math.round(currentPrice * 100) / 100;

    /* Add current price of this iteration to end of array */
    resultsArray.push(currentPrice);
  }

  /* Return the array */
  return resultsArray;
};

console.log(handleCalculate());
```

Comment: As for your edit of whether its good practice. It is common practice to do it the way the other answers have (ie create an array etc). It is not best practice in my opinion however as you don't get the upsides of lazy evalutation (ie using yield) and you formally declare an array (as opposed to not needing to).

Comment: @Dessus thanks for your comment - sorry I'm not following? :)

Answer (score 0):

The way to do it in the specific way you have asked the question is to use the yield return. This is documented here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/yield

Essentially instead of using return (which breaks the loop) you use yield which returns a value of an iterable (but only when iterating that far). This is a great way to program as you could say have 10,000 items but have a consumer only ready the top 10 etc. This would prevent the need to process all 10,000 for someone only wanting a few items. This approach would also mean less than a 1 line change for you.

It also means that you don't need to create an array as in the other answers.

```
const handleCalculate = () => {
  let price = 6.6;
  let growthRate = 12.35;
  let yearlyGrowth = (growthRate * price) / 100;
  let currentPrice = price + yearlyGrowth;

  for (let i = 0; i <= 10; i++) {
    currentPrice += yearlyGrowth;
    currentPrice = Math.round(currentPrice * 100) / 100;

    /* Add current price of this iteration to end of array */
    yield currentPrice;
  }
};

console.log(handleCalculate().next().value); //this only loops once in that for loop. Note: handleCalculate() returns an iterable (meaning its only executed once .next() or similar is called on it. This makes it lazy evaluated.
console.log(handleCalculate().next().value); //this is the 2nd iteration result
console.log(Array.from(handleCalculate()); //this forces execution of your entire for loop (like the other answers) and outputs an array.
```

Comment: Looks good, but i'm very new in JavaScript development, i'll look at it later.

Comment: Literally change your 'return' to 'yield'. Then treat the result as an array from the method.

Comment: Have included updated code sample. See the 3 different ways of getting results at the bottom. It shows stuff that can't be done with the other approaches. It also reduces code in your function.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it is ok?

---

```
``const handleCalculate = () => { 
  let price = 6.60;
  let growthRate = 12.35;
  let yearlyGrowth = (growthRate * price) / 100;
  let currentPrice = price + yearlyGrowth;
  return ()=>{
    currentPrice += yearlyGrowth; 
    currentPrice = Math.round(currentPrice * 100) / 100;
    //how can i return each values instead of console.log()?
    //console.log(currentPrice);
  }
}
btn.addEventListener('click',handleCalculate())
```